# Why the following discrete inequality are equal?

Tags: pde, numerics, discretization

When reviewing papers on the numerical solutions of Partial Differential Equations (PDEs), I observed the following equation:
$$
(1-C\tau)||\theta^n||^2 \leq ||\theta^{n-1}||^2 + C\tau (h^{2r+2}),
$$
where $\tau$ is the discrete time step, and $h$ is the spactial step size. The above equation is equal to
$$
||\theta^n||^2 \leq (1+C\tau)||\theta^{n-1}||^2 + C\tau (h^{2r+2}),
$$
What is the reason why the above formulas are equivalent?

Comment: $C$ is typically considered a "generic constant" in these sorts of estimates, i.e., it may have a different value in the two equations. See if you can show the equivalence if (i) you rename $C$ to $D$ in the second line, and (ii) ignore all terms higher order in $\tau$ and $h$.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thx! ignoring all terms of higher order is a good idea